# Hide navigator's top outline outside of selection

Tags: highcharts

I'm working on a Highchart plot using a navigator and I've noticed that my outline color is applied to the whole navigator's top, not just the selected data range.

To visualize:
[image]
I'm talking about the purple line going through the whole chart, while I'd like it to be just a part of the selection box, the rest of the top outline should have different color/width. How can I achieve that?

Here's a snippet for reference, found it online and it's rather simple but it shows exactly what's happening:

```js
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

    navigator: {
        outlineColor: 'blue',
        outlineWidth: 2,
        series: {
            lineWidth: 3,
          fillOpacity: 0.3
        }
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'USD to EUR',
        data: usdeur
    }]
});
```

```html
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 600px"></div>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/usdeur.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the blue lines are created by one svg path element. The only way to change a navigator outline is to wrap the function responsible for drawing it and change its path.

For example:

```
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H.Navigator.prototype, 'drawOutline', function(procced, zoomedMin, zoomedMax, inverted, verb) {
    var navigator = this,
      maskInside = navigator.navigatorOptions.maskInside,
      outlineWidth = navigator.outline.strokeWidth(),
      halfOutline = outlineWidth / 2,
      outlineCorrection = (outlineWidth % 2) / 2, // #5800
      outlineHeight = navigator.outlineHeight,
      scrollbarHeight = navigator.scrollbarHeight,
      navigatorSize = navigator.size,
      left = navigator.left - scrollbarHeight,
      navigatorTop = navigator.top,
      verticalMin,
      path;

    if (inverted) {
      left -= halfOutline;
      verticalMin = navigatorTop + zoomedMax + outlineCorrection;
      zoomedMax = navigatorTop + zoomedMin + outlineCorrection;

      path = [
        'M',
        left + outlineHeight,
        navigatorTop - scrollbarHeight - outlineCorrection, // top edge
        'L',
        left + outlineHeight,
        verticalMin, // top right of zoomed range
        'L',
        left,
        verticalMin, // top left of z.r.
        'L',
        left,
        zoomedMax, // bottom left of z.r.
        'L',
        left + outlineHeight,
        zoomedMax, // bottom right of z.r.
        'L',
        left + outlineHeight,
        navigatorTop + navigatorSize + scrollbarHeight // bottom edge
      ].concat(maskInside ? [
        'M',
        left + outlineHeight,
        verticalMin - halfOutline, // upper left of zoomed range
        'L',
        left + outlineHeight,
        zoomedMax + halfOutline // upper right of z.r.
      ] : []);
    } else {
      zoomedMin += left + scrollbarHeight - outlineCorrection;
      zoomedMax += left + scrollbarHeight - outlineCorrection;
      navigatorTop += halfOutline;

      path = [
        'M',
        zoomedMin,
        navigatorTop, // upper left of zoomed range
        'L',
        zoomedMin,
        navigatorTop + outlineHeight, // lower left of z.r.
        'L',
        zoomedMax,
        navigatorTop + outlineHeight, // lower right of z.r.
        'L',
        zoomedMax,
        navigatorTop, // upper right of z.r.
      ].concat(maskInside ? [
        'M',
        zoomedMin - halfOutline,
        navigatorTop, // upper left of zoomed range
        'L',
        zoomedMax + halfOutline,
        navigatorTop // upper right of z.r.
      ] : []);
    }
    navigator.outline[verb]({
      d: path
    });

  });
}(Highcharts));
```

---

**Live example:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lrgok19a/

**Useful thread:** https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=41155

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much it. I tired asking this question on the highcharts forum as well but here goes: is it possible to animate that drawing somehow? I'm talking about the moment when you click on a place in the navigator. You can see it even in the provided fiddle that the rectangles draws immediately and the handles follow shortly. And I'm not talking about disabling the animations completely. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Hi @Marcin Zareba, I am glad that I could help :) The animation is only a matter of a different path structure. Here is a simplified example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/k7635sto/

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed, thank you sooo much!